# How to retrieve list of metadata components added to Package on Package org through API?

Tags: apex, api, metadata, package, org

We want to develop tool which compare metadata files from Pull Request with metadata components which were already added to Package on Package org. To accomplish this we need to get list of already added components.

Is it possible to get list of metadata components already added to Package on Package org through any API?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to retrieve the list of package components without actually retrieving the package via the Metadata API.

You can do this by making a [`retrieve()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm) call. In your [`RetrieveRequest`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve_request.htm), you specify the name of the managed package being developed in the packaging org in the `packageNames` element.

The ZIP file that you get back in response will include both the components of the package as well as a `package.xml` defining the package content. You can parse the `package.xml` to get details of which components are already included.

Answer (score 0):

FYI for packaging 2 only, the Tooling API allows the [Page2Member](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_package2member.htm) records to be queried including in the Developer Console that lists all the components in a package.